# How to get jupyter cell output to update continuously

Tags: python, output, jupyter, live, psutil

I have seen several cases of streamz as well as simple code updating live in the output from a jupyter cell, but when I try this myself I only get one value output unless I run a loop or continually press Ctrl-Enter to update. The simplest example is just a single line of code in a cell:

`psutil.cpu_percent()`

I've seen videos and gifs showing the output updating continuously, apparently with no extra magics or other special settings and I'd like to see my cell in jupyter lab update in this same way. What am I doing wrong?

**More background:** This began when I started trying to duplicate the streamz examples in [Streaming Dataframes](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/10/16/streaming-dataframes-1) from Matthew Rocklin. I tried the following code:

```
source = Random(freq='5ms', interval='100ms')
source.x.sum()
```

Have a look at the example about halfway down the page in the link under 'Jupyter Integration and Streaming Outputs' and you'll see what I mean. In the example, this code generates a continuously updating output below the cell, but when I try it, it delivers only a single value, which only updates if I run the cell again. Since that didn't work as advertised, I tried this other example I'd seen with psutil, and that didn't work either. So I figure there must be something wrong with my jupyter settings, but I don't know what it might be. Again, I realize I might be able to replicate this behavior using a loop, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong to keep this from working simply as shown.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you want to update? Maybe you can create an infinite loop that does the update.

Comment: At this point I'm just trying to demonstrate to myself that I can get a cell in jupyter to output continuously updating information. In the examples I've seen, the output for a cell containing nothing more than ```psutil.cpu_percent()``` displayed a continuously changing value showing current cpu use. When I try to replicate this, the output displays a single static value that does not update unless I create such a loop or repeatedly press Ctrl-Enter.

Comment: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=cpu_percent#psutil.cpu_percent, You could try to set the interval.

Comment: I tried this by changing my one line of code to ```psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)``` but the behavior is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for.
This will output the cpu percentage every second. But will block your current kernel.

```
import psutil

while True:
    print(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1.))
```

Comment: Really, I'm just trying to figure out why I can't duplicate what I've seen elsewhere, namely that a cell output is updated in real time without any loops. I do realize I could do it with a loop, but having seen it work without a loop, I want to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've figured this out for myself, although I'm still not entirely sure. I was under the impression that the streamz examples in [Streaming Dataframes](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/10/16/streaming-dataframes-1) were running with no additional widgets or code, but then I looked at [Matthew Rocklin - Streaming Processing with Dask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI_yZoUaz60&t=740s) on YouTube, and roughly at time 12:00 he introduces an async routine to push data into a stream in a loop:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

async def f():
while True:
    await gen.sleep(0.100)
    record = create_record()
    source.emit(record, asynchronous = True)

IOLoop.current().add_callback(f)
```

I can't claim I understand what is going on here, because I'm still a Jupyter novice and never knew anything about asynchronous code before trying these examples, but since this appears to work, I was evidently missing this key information when asking the question.